# Solving double derivative $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = f(y)$ by integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to ask if a differential equation of second order can be solved by integration? Like equations of the type $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = f(y)$. I know this can be solved by making equations of the form $(D² - a²)y = c$ Where $D$ is the operator $\dfrac{d(•)}{dx}$. But I want to know can this be solved using direct integration. In particular my equation is $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = (1-y)$.

Answer (score 2):

The general case is
$$\frac{d^{2}y(x)}{dx^{2}}=Y(y(x))$$
One has
$$\frac{d^{2}y(x)}{dx^{2}}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=y'\frac{dy'}{dy}$$ 
Thus
$$y'\frac{dy'}{dy}=Y(y)$$
Or
$$y'dy'=Y(y)dy$$
Integrating the both sides we get
$$(y')^{2}=2\int^{y}Y(z)dz+C_{1}$$
Or,
$$y'(x)=\pm\sqrt{2\int^{y}Y(z)dz+C_{1}}$$
The equation is separble, thus
$$\pm(x+C_{2})=\int^{y}\frac{dw}{\sqrt{2\int^{w}Y(z)dz+C_{1}}}$$

Comment: Beautiful! Really Insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it can. Illustrating with your equation: we have 
$$
((y')^2)'=2y'y''=2y'(1-y)
$$
and so
$$
((y')^2)'=(2y-y^2)'.
$$
Integrating on both sides gives
$$
(y')^2=2y-y^2+c
$$
for some $c$ and so
$$
y'=\pm\sqrt{2y-y^2+c}.
$$
You need to solve the last equation, for each $c$ and each sign $\pm$, and then substitute in the original equation. This last step is necessary in view of the $\pm$ signs since you don't know if you got more than the solutions of the original equation.

Comment: Thanks John B. I was looking for much generalised solution. But I got the idea how it could be done for any f(y). 

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be solved by direct integration.
Let $u=y'+iy$ then from $y''+y=1$ we obtain
$$e^{-ix}(y''+y)=e^{-ix}(u'-iu)=D(e^{-ix}u)=e^{-ix}\cdot 1$$
By integrating it, we get
$$e^{-ix}u=ie^{-ix}+c_1$$
that is, after multiplying both sides by $e^{2ix}$,
$$D(e^{ix}y)=e^{ix}(y'+iy)=e^{ix}i+c_1e^{2ix}.$$
Again, by integrating it, we get
$$e^{ix}y=e^{ix}-2ic_1e^{2ix}+c_2$$
that is
$$y=1-2ic_1e^{ix}+c_2e^{-ix}=1+C_1e^{ix}+C_2e^{-ix}$$
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary complex constants.

Comment:  thanks Robert Z

Comment: @user29918 Glad to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

In general for a equation of the form $f(y,y^\prime,y^{\prime\prime})=0$‎ which $x$ doesn't appear in it, we let $y^\prime=u$ then
$$y^{\prime\prime}=\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=uu^\prime$$‎
and the equation will be of the form $f(y,u,uu^\prime)=0$. This is a equation of the first order of ‎$u$ respect to ‎$y$, where $u^\prime=\dfrac{du}{dy}$.

For your example $y''=1-y$, then $uu'=1-y$ or $u\dfrac{du}{dy}=1-y$ which can be solved by separation.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks 